# Validity of Contraposition.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Contraposition says:
$$
P \implies Q \iff \neg Q \implies \neg P
$$

What if P means "Santa Claus is in town" and Q means "I am in town"?
It would mean:
If Santa Claus is in town, then I am in town.
Due to contraposition it also means:
If I am not in town, then Santa Clause is also not in town. So, I am the reason why Santa Clause is not in town.

Based on this, P causes Q and vice versa. But I think there could be more than one reason why P does not happen other than that Q does not happen. The reason why Santa Clause is not in town could be because of many other reasons and not just because I am not in town.Or what is my misunderstanding here?

Comment: "So I am the reason Santa Claus is not in town". How did you come to that judgement?

Comment: @user2277550 because of the contrapositive:  If I am not in town, then Santa Clause is also not in town.

Comment: It could mean "Since I am closely following Santa on his trip from Norway, I will definitely go and shake hands with him if he comes to my native town".

Comment: Yes.. "If I am not in town, then Santa Clause is also not in town" does not in any way imply that I "caused" Santa to not be in town.

Comment: @user2277550 ...my absence means SC's absence. Isn't that what the sentence "If I am not in town, then Santa Clause is also not in town" says?

Comment: It definitely "$means$" but doesnt imply "$causation$" .

Comment: Look at it this way..."Since I am closely following Santa on his trip from Norway, I will definitely go and shake hands with him if he comes to my native town---but since he has caught a cold,he is not coming to my native town, and hence I am not going to my town either." You did not cause the cold obviously. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of "cause" here - it doesn't generalize that easily.

Consider the statements P = "The Aggies win the next football game" and Q = "I win the bet I made with Tom." So, $P \implies Q$ means "If the Aggies win the next football game, then I win the bet I made with Tom." Consider the contrapositive: "If I lost the bet I made with Tom, then the Aggies lost the next football game." Think of this: The Aggies win, I win my bet. But if I lost my bet, then certainly the Aggies lost. The same reasoning, huh?

But try this, if I won the bet, does that mean the Aggies won? Not necessarily. Fallacy of the converse.